# Error using SqlAdapter '{"Must declare the table variable \"@tableName\"."}'

Tags: sql, asp.net

I can't see where i'm going wrong and was wondering if you could help at all?
Just a basic SELECT with a table.
With regards to the error message, i thought i was declaring the @tableName variable in the parameters section?

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
                              "SELECT * FROM @tableName",con);

                        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                         {
                             ParameterName = "@tableName",
                             Value = tableName,
                             SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
                         });                            
                        adapter.Fill(databaseList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`From` clause not be expression so, cant send parameter

Try this

```
  SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(string.Format("Select * From {0}", "yourTableName"), con);
```

Comment: This is SQL injection. The name must be *properly* quoted.

Comment: yes this is SQL injection but any way to native SqlQuery?  Maybe check table name if exist from db. @RemusRusanu

Comment: Yes, I did originally have this: 
SqlDataAdapter adapter =
                                new SqlDataAdapter(
                                    $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}",
                                    con);
But it would have been nice to parameterize it. 

Never mind. 

Thanks, all.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass table **names** to SELECT as a parameter. Construct your SQL dynamically, by inserting the properly quoted (escaped) table name in the SQL string.